I am unable to read data validation cells values in excel when using excel package in flutter
I am using excel package in my flutter project to read excel file. When I try to read an excel file that contains dropdown values/ data validation cells , Excel.decodeBytes(bytes) unable to read the selected values and it brings null data. I appreciate for any of your assistance.
This is the file I want to read :
exce_file.xlsx
My pubspec.yaml file:
excel: ^4.0.3
file_picker: ^8.0.0+1

Here is my code:
Excel? excelFile;

List? excelData;

pickFiles() async {
 /// to clear the cache
 var document = await getTemporaryDirectory();
 document.delete(recursive: true);

 /// to pick an excel
 var result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
   type: FileType.custom,
   allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
 );

 if (result != null) {
  var first = result.files.first;
  var bytes = File(first.path!).readAsBytesSync();
  Excel excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

